# Animate stop when change uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3

I write marquee text for first view controller but change the controller and back the first view controller marquee text is not working.

First Controller Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var marqueeText: UILabel!        

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 16.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
        marqueeText.center = CGPoint(x: 0 -marqueeText.center.bounds.size.width / 2, y: text.center.y)
    }, completion:  { _ in })

}
```

Comment: Put the animation code in another function, and recall the function in viewDidAppear.

Comment: extension UIViewController {
        
        func marquee (text: UILabel) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 16.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
            text.center = CGPoint(x: 0 - text.bounds.size.width / 2, y: text.center.y)
        }, completion:  { _ in })
        
    }
    
}


This is my function and i use this: 

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        marquee(text: marqueeText)
    }

But this is not working

Comment: call that in viewdidload too for first time animation

Comment: i did but it is not working again. Do you test it this code?

Comment: You shouldn't put the animation in an extension of `UIViewController`, because it's specific to your concrete view controller. BTW: _But is not working_ is not a statement that others can relate to.

Comment: I try function without extension. But same problem i change view controller and stop it then back animation its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var marqueeText: UILabel!

var marqueeTextPoint = CGPoint()
var stopAnim: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    marqueeTextPoint = marqueeText.center
    marquee(text: marqueeText)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.marqueeText.center = self.marqueeTextPoint
    marquee(text: marqueeText)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    stopAnim = true
}

func marquee (text: UILabel) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 16.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {
        text.center = CGPoint(x: 0 - text.bounds.size.width / 2, y: text.center.y)
    }, completion: { _ in
        if !(self.stopAnim) {
            self.marquee(text: text)
        } else  {
            text.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It is working but iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone SE not sit in view.